# Does Browser cache React website -HTML, JS, CSS, Images files?

Tags: javascript, html

How does a React based website works. JS file and HTML files get cached in browser or all files are downloaded on user browser every time when they hit the application URL? Or is this something browser specific? some browser cache by default and some do not?
What code to be written in React Page / component so browser Cache it?

Read this link: https://web.dev/http-cache/

Comment: The browser will cache what it's told to cache, React is no different here..

Comment: Yes, the browser will generally cache what it can to save needing to refetch files if they haven't changed. Do you have some issue or problem you need help with?

Comment: What code to be written in React Page / component so browser Cache it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.